# Are grammatical errors allowed in provisional application?

Tags: provisional-application

English is not my first language. I'm about to file Provisional application. But it might contain grammatical errors. I'm planning to hire a patent attorney for drafting the non provisional. Can I file the provisional now with grammatical errors and fix later in non provisional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are allowed and if they don't alter the content they are not a problem. Mistakes that make something unclear or change the meaning of the sentence should be avoided - they cannot be corrected when filing the non provisional.

If a change introduced with the non provisional introduces a substantial change, you lose the priority date for that changed content - and if the change is not substantial the mistake wasn't substantial. In that case it can be corrected but there is no need to - and introducing changes without need bears the danger of invalidation if a court later later finds the change to have been substantial.

See [this question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/17337/18033) and its answer for more information. Maca explained in the answer why changes shouldn't be made, too. Spelling might be fine, grammar however is already dangerous.

TL;DR: no.